# getElementById() for children of an element

Tags: javascript

`getElementById()` is on the `document` object.

If I have an element reference already, how can I find the child (or children's child etc) that has a given ID?

```
var parent = document.getElementById(parentId),
    child = parent.getElementById(childId);
```

This code fails because normal elements on a page do not have a `getElementById` method.

(I'm in maintenance mode, IDs are not necessarily unique, and cannot use jQuery).

Comment: you could show some relavant code....

Comment: Why are your IDs not unique, any reason?  If (for some weird reason I can't think of) you must have non-unique IDs, you could use `getElementsByTagName` or something similar.

Comment: This makes no sense. This implies that you want to assign the same ID more than once.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy and Amberlamps - The OP stated that he is "in maintenance mode". That is, he is forced to work with an existing html codebase that has duplicated IDs.

Comment: Ah - sorry about that.  As I had said before, you could use some other methods of finding the element involved, however `getElementById` won't work at all.

Comment: Do you only have the ID in question or do you have some other info at your disposal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector):

```
child = parent.querySelector("#" + childId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop all the child nodes yourself?

Something like this perhaps:

```
GetChildElementByID = function (rootElement, id){
    var children = GetAllNodes(rootElement);
    for(var i in children){
        var element = children[i];
        if(element.id == id){
            return element;
        } 
    }
    return null;
}

GetAllNodes = function (rootElement) {
    var nodes = [];
    var childNodes = rootElement.childNodes;
    for (var i in childNodes) {
        var node = childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType) {
            nodes.push(node);
        }
        nodes.push.apply(nodes, GetAllNodes(node));
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

query selectors can find children of parents.

`document.querySelector("#parentID > #childID");`